# mklink /d not working

Tags: windows-8, symbolic-link, network-drive, mklink, file-server

I have a folder with my pictures on a network drive. I would like that folder in the pictures library in windows 8. It wouldn't let me add it since the network drive isn't indexed. Windows help said this could be accomplished by creating a folder and adding it to the library, then deleting the folder and then running a series of commands to create a "symbolic link". I've created and deleted the folder and added that to the library. The location is c:\FILESERVER\Pictures. The location of the pictures folder I've been trying to add is \FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures.

To create the symbolic link I've been using mklink /d "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" "\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures".

This has been returning an error stating that the path couldn't be found. Any thoughts?

Update: Seems to be a real issue that others have noticed as well, I still haven't been able to get it working even with much help from STTR. I was able to add the pictures to the library while on the server by modifying the location of the My pictures folder that is in the library already but it remains unindexed and thus unusable by the picture viewer app etc. Hopefully a service pack or patch will fix this soon.

Comment: fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation - may be symbolic link disabled?

Comment: If symbolic link is disabled how could I go about re-enabling it? Not sure I understood the first part of your comment...

Comment: fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2L:1 R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1

Comment: Just tried it. After I ran that I ran the original command and it's still saying the syntax is invalid. I've checked and rechecked and it's the same as in the Microsoft help docs.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx Junction - Sysinternals Suite Utilities? eq mklink - work? FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures - network resource? - mklink /d "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" "\\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures"

Comment: may be space in way ... use - mklink /d "dir 1" "dir 2"

Comment: Adding the quotes around the directories fixed the syntax error but now it's just saying that the path can't be found.

Comment: mklink /d "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" "c:\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures" mklink /d "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" "\\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures" cd "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" cd "c:\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures" cd "\\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures" ? powershell Get-Eventlog system -Source Disk  powershell Get-Eventlog system -newest 10 -EntryType Error -Source Disk ? may be HDD problem?

Comment: I can't use cd to change the directory to c:\FILESERVER\Pictures because it's not there. The help docs in windows said to delete it after adding it to the library and before setting up the symbolic link

Comment: md "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" cd "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" ?

Comment: When I ran it with md to create the new directory it said a file already existed...

Comment: I don't think it's an HDD issue. Windows 8 is running on a RAID 5 array

Comment: RAID 5 - not good idea use RAID 10 or 6 ... if RAID 5 crash - you not repaer it) ... RAID 5 work good at smallest hdd size 120-140Gb ... See RAID state

Comment: Changing from RAID 5 isn't an option right now. Any other ideas to get the symbolic link to work?

Comment: Create a new empty directory and link to it.

Comment: I also tried to map \\FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents as a network drive (L:) and then use L:\Pictures instead of the other path incase it didn't like the UNC path. Still nothing. Can't find the directory.

Comment: It's saying it can't create it because it already exists

Comment: "c:\FILESERVER\Pictures" - empty folder?

Comment: Yes, it's empty

Comment: \\FILESERVER - external network station?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: net view - get 6118 error? in \\FILESERVER and local station?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7294/discussion-between-sttr-and-blake)

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itpronetworking/thread/b5e785fa-689b-441f-b7ae-020e335c98ca  may be help ... see later)

Comment: install last firmware and tools to TeraStation ... [Software Release Notes]
Version 1.13
- Compatible with Windows 8.
http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/professional-and-business-class-nas/terastation-pro-8  ... choice you model

Comment: Did you try the command from both normal and elevated command prompts? If neither works, try `mklink /d C:\Pictures \FILESERVER\DATA\My Documents\Pictures` instead from both normal and elevated command prompts and see if that works. You can also try `/j` instead of `/d`.

Comment: Tried everything I could and still couldn't get it to work as intended. I did change the location of "My Pictures" in the pictures Library by right clicking and clicking properties and then location and modifying that to the path of the server pictures folder. It is still of course unindexed. In the end I believe I might just have to keep anything local that I want both in a Library and indexed. Possibly a service pack will correct this issue soon. Thanks to STTR for all the help!! If you want to leave an answer summarizing what I found I'll mark it as best so you get the reputation points :)

Comment: Just curious, are you able to create a junction to a local drive?

Comment: I believe I would be able to, I could do so with two folders on the same drive. I could grab a flash drive tomorrow and test it to see.

Comment: @I doubt it wouldn't work, then.

Comment: The problem may be even in different implementations of the protocol SMB (NetBIOS).
Windows 8 - SMB 3.0, linux - SMB 2.1. It can be connected to Windows 7/XP?